# How to make a search form and allow selections from other Entities ? Symfony 6.0.2

Tags: forms, symfony, entities

I'm trying to create a search form where the user can search for an event by selecting its city and category. So I would like to create two selections "city" and "category" with the options already saved in the database.

More information :

- I created an "Event" entity that has a "category" field. This field is connected to the "Category" entity by a ManyToOne.
- The "Event" entity has a "location" field, connected to the "Location" entity by a ManyToOne. But it's the "Location" entity that has a "city" field.

For later :

I'll save it for later... but I'd also like to create a country selection. The "Country" entity is created and it is connected by a OneToMany to the "City" entity. And if the city is selected without its country, the country would be defined automatically.

EDIT :

EventSearchType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Events;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class SearchType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('bigcity', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Location::class,
                'choice_label' => 'bigcity',
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => null
        ]);
    }
}
```

events.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Liste des sorties et des activités{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<div class="page position-relative">

    <div class="form container position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle">
        {{ form(form) }}
    </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

EventsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Events;
use App\Entity\BigCity;
use App\Entity\Country;
use App\Entity\Categories;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SearchType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class EventsController extends AbstractController
{    
    #[Route('/search', name: 'search')]
    public function search(Request $request)
    {   
        $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            return $this->render('front/events.html.twig', $data);
        }
        return $this->render('front/search.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create EventSearchType and put inside all fields you need and using EntityType. in The configuration of this class you can say 'data_class'=> null

Comment: Ok tous. I am using one field to test. I added the code in description. Is it correct ?

Comment: Yes but if you want you can put null in data_class instead of Events::class

Comment: Ok, it's good. I have at least one input displayed where I can enter text. How do I get a selection instead ?

Comment: But "bigcity" is an EntityType it's already a selection, not text input !!!. It must be displayed as a select choice in the form view, this is not the case for you ??

Comment: I am afraid no... I am posting the content of my html.twig.

Comment: And the controller...

Comment: The template view is named search.html.twig or events.html.twig ? In the return in the controller is search.html.twig, do you have the correct form view there ? Can you delete the cache and try again ?

Comment: I want to display the form in search.html.twig and redirect after validating the form to events.html.twig.

Comment: Yes, the cache are empty. The problem remains the same.

Comment: In search.html.twig do you have this code or no ?  {{ form(form) }}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248153/discussion-between-emilie-tossan-and-hous).

Answer (score 1):

This was my mistake : **App\Form\SearchType** instead of **Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SearchType** in EventsController.php file.

It's working properly now. :)